# Maven complains about dependency to a WAR file

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a project which has a following dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.richfaces.examples</groupId>
     <artifactId>richfaces-showcase</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
     <classifier>jbas71</classifier>
     <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

While the WAR file seems to be on the right place in my local repo. Contents of `.m2/repository/org/richfaces/examples/richfaces-showcase/4.3.4.Final/`

- richfaces-showcase-4.3.4.Final-jbas71.war
- richfaces-showcase-4.3.4.Final-jbas71.war.lastUpdated
- richfaces-showcase-4.3.4.Final-jbas71.war.pom

I tried to delete the `*.lastUpdated` file, `*.war.pom` seems to be ok too but I am still getting

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project richfaces-showcase-portlet: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jboss.portletbridge.examples:richfaces-showcase-portlet:war:3.3.1.Final: 
Failure to find org.richfaces.examples:richfaces-showcase:war:jbas71:4.3.4.Final in
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution 
will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are 
forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: When you delete the war from local repository (.m2) and run mvn install what happen ?

Comment: I'm sure you tried using the `-U` force update option?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup: Sure, I forgot to mention it

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup `-U` is only for SNAPSOTS which will not help in this case cause this is a releasae.

Comment: Argh of course - my bad.

Answer (score 2):

The dependency is imply wrong, cause a war file is not intended to be a dependency. The war file is intended to be use as an example which can be deployed into a Tomcat etc. to see how it looks like etc.

Apart from that you are trying to get richfaces from Maven Central which is not possible cause  Richfaces is not in Maven Central. They have their own repository. You need to add this repository to your configuration or Repository manager.

Furthermore the message:

```
Failure to find org.richfaces.examples:richfaces-showcase:war:jbas71:4.3.4.Final in
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution 
will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are 
forced -> [Help 1]
```

shows that the dependency couldn't be downloaded. I assume the size of the war file is 0..

Comment: Size WAR is few MBs, so that seems fine. And yes, the WAR is not in Maven central but I have it locally so that should be fine, shouldn't it?I am using it in a subproject for overlay with Maven WAR plugin so that's why I need to depend on it.

Comment: What do you mean by having it locally? The message says you are accessing Maven central. Ok. For a overlay this is a different story which you didn't mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that I have this artifact installed in local repo but Maven is obviously not able to find it so it tries Maven central which will of course fail. So the question is why?The correct WAR is in the right folder in my local repo, so why is Maven not able to find it during build?

Comment: How did you install it (command)? Why not using a repository manager (Artifactory, Nexus, Archiva) will make life easier.

Comment: I used `mvn install`. Well, repository managed doesn't help me with my problem right now, does it?

Comment: If you used mvn install you have build it from source? not via `mvn install:install-file` The repository manager would help you. Just define the richfaces repository in repo manager and you can use it.

Comment: Yes, I have a sources, so I am able to build that WAR file and install it into my local repo which should be enough, isn't it?I can define richfaces repo as a workaround but it seems to me like an overkill since what I am doing right now seems like a easiest way.

Comment: Have you checked the GAV's to be correct, cause it doesn't look like that?

Comment: Is there anything else concerning GAV I should check besides the information I posted in question?

Comment: @khmarbaise : Just a nitpick - it's not applicable in this case, but, in general, WARs **can** be intended as dependencies. [Overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) come to mind, for example.